# How to detect url change using jquery (or javascript) for urls without a hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been searching for an answer to this and the most I can find is to use window hashchange.  However my urls do not contain hashes.

Please note that I do not have any control over the urls or the code for the sites.

So here is what I am doing.  I create a drop down button with a few options.

Button A -> Option 1, Option 2, Option 3, etc....

How the site is designed is this.  The base url is
http://example.com/12345zzzyyyxxx

To modify anything on that page, you need to click on the edit button.  This will take you to the url (which is the edit page)
http://example.com/12345uuuyyyttt/e

As you can see above, 12345 is a constant and anything after that (up to the /e on the second url) is dynamic.  But no hashes.

So I am trying to automate the following:
1. Click on Edit
2. Fill in the required fields based on option selected.
3. Save the changes.  Once save is triggered, the site will take automatically take you back to /12345zzzyyyxxx base url.

So I have it working from the edit page, but that means you have to manually click on edit.  I want to automate that.

I have tried using setTimeout and setInterval to detect when this happens, but what I have found out during debugging is that both of these go out of scope when the frame changes.

Also note that the entire page does not change, the frame changes keeping the logo and a few other items untouched and you can physically see that they stay while the frame changes.

Comment: Is an [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) or a *traditional* setup? If the latter, meaning simple http requests to transition from page to page, then no javascript residing on only one of those pages can do what you want. You would need two pieces of code working independently using some medium for communication (url, local storage, cookies...).

Comment: I'm going to say traditional.  The edit button has an url attached to the onclick function.  Yet the top frames stay intact and never reload.  Its salesforce, so unsure if that would be an SPA or traditional.

Answer (score 0):

History JS is basically the standard js-lib to handle all History state changes, check their github account for more information.

https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/